# Create views for user profile management

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have the below schema for user profile management,

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users 
  ( 
     userid     TEXT NOT NULL, 
     name       TEXT NULL, 
     lmessage   INTEGER NULL, 
     statusid   INTEGER NULL,  
     /* statusid should refer to last status of the user in status table*/
     locationid INTEGER NULL,  
     /* locationid should refer to last status of the user in locations table */
     registered INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     tinypic    INTEGER NULL 
     /* this refers to media id in media table */, 
     largepic   INTEGER NULL 
     /* this also refers to media id in media table */,
     groupid    INTEGER NULL 
     /* this refers to id in groups table */ ,
     PRIMARY KEY (userid) 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS locations 
  ( 
     serial INTEGER,
     locationid TEXT NOT NULL, 
     userid TEXT NOT NULL,
     time     INTEGER NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (serial) 
  );  

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS status 
  (
     serial INTEGER,
     userid TEXT NULL,
     message  TEXT NOT NULL, 
     time     INTEGER NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (serial) 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages 
  ( 
     sno       INTEGER, 
     messageid INTEGER NOT NULL, 
     sender    TEXT NOT NULL, 
     receiver  TEXT NOT NULL, 
     time      INTEGER NULL, 
     message   TEXT NULL, 
     image     INTEGER NULL, 
     video     INTEGER NULL, 
     audio     INTEGER NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (sno) 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS media 
  ( 
     mediaid    TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE, 
     url        TEXT NULL, 
     downloaded INTEGER NULL, 
     thumbnail  TEXT NULL, 
     PRIMARY KEY (mediaid) 
  ); 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS groups 
  (
     serial INTEGER,
     name TEXT NOT NULL,
     id INTEGER NOT NULL
     PRIMARY KEY(serial)
  );


CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS id_unique ON users (userid ASC); 

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS serial_unique ON status (serial ASC); 

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS id_unique ON messages (sno ASC); 

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS serial_unique ON patterns (serial DESC); 

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS mediaid_unique ON media (mediaid ASC);
```

How can create views on user table to get list of users based on filter conditions. Please suggest me schema design is not good.

A view example that I would like to add on this schema :

1. Select all users who belong to group and all groups created after that group.
2. Select all users with last message, status, location and media urls included.

Thanks.

Please Note that I am SQL nube, please forgive me if you feel like this is immature question. All I need is, I want to learn from reviews of other people.

Comment: I might forgive you, but Stack Overflow does not. You are supposed to ask only one question. Furthermore, questions must be *specific*; this is not a site to teach you the basics of SQL queries.

Comment: @Cl Yes, I agree with that. But I had come up with relevant questions with some background work too :)

Answer (score 0):

for 1 - you need to have timestamp (INTEGER id you go by UTC ticks) in group table - it is missing

for 2 - you can do it with join

bot case i don't think you need to have a view unless you have some specific reasons. You can go by select queries with join to get required data.

I recommend you to use http://www.sqliteexpert.com/download.html - try out creating the schema there and try out all your queries before you get in to implementing it in android

Comment: I will be retrieving the same data for every few seconds. So thought, views will make it better